# Regarding the equation of continuity in magnetostatics

Tags: magnetostatics

Griffiths says that for a steady current and uniform conductivity
DivE = (1/σ)divJ = 0. This is obtained by taking divergence of equation
E =(1/σ)J .
But from equation of continuity we know         div J = dρ/dt. For steady current, div j is 0 implying ρ is constant( may be non zero constant or 0) with time.
But Griffiths says div E is zero which is when ρ is 0 ( from gauss law) .
Then why the ρ is constant as 0 not a non zero constant.
Why we would consider ρ to be 0 even though that it may be a non zero constant.
Does it have any thing to do with conductivity.??
Plz explain.

Comment: Where does he say this?

Comment: Chapter electrodynamics,.  just before example example 7.3